# How to create a custom ID on Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to create an ID during extraction of data (scraping) on Python, so I need to give to each phrase an ID like (A50001) where A is a letter that is the initial letter of site, 5 is a number of stars and 0001 is the number of phrases.
How I can do it?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not hard, and you're expected to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: No such "attempt" is expected, @TimRoberts. Please do not spread misinformation. As long as the question is a practical, programming problem with sufficient focus to be answered in a Q&A format, then it is a legitimate question for Stack Overflow. There are no "effort" or "attempt" requirements, nor are there rules prohibiting simple ("not hard") questions. If the question or problem statement is unclear, then that is an issue, but, if so, you should be asking about that instead of making vague allusions to a lack of effort or implying the asker is lazy.

Comment: I think you will find many who disagree with you.  This is not supposed to be a code-writing service.

Comment: @TimRoberts i don't know where to start, i can print A and number of stars but i don't know how to print "0001", when i print the index of "for" i get 1,2,3 ecc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i created like this:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
  id = sitecode + str(stars) + str(i).zfill(4)
```

Comment: No, you didn't.  That code won't work.  If you're going to provide and answer, you should include the correct code, like `id = sitecode + str(stars) + str(i).zfill(4)`.